# Does the fraction of positive integers not being a Carmichael value have a limit?

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, carmichael-function

Let $f(n)$ be the number of positive integers $x\le n$ such that $\lambda(k)=x$ has no solution, where $\lambda(k)$ denotes the Carmichael-function.

> Does $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}$$ exist , and if yes, is it $1$ or some smaller value ?

The last few lines in a numerical analysis were :

```
579000000  0.77069874093264248704663212435233160622
580000000  0.77070391551724137931034482758620689655
581000000  0.77070938382099827882960413080895008606
582000000  0.77071472164948453608247422680412371134
583000000  0.77071994511149228130360205831903945112
584000000  0.77072559931506849315068493150684931507
585000000  0.77073061196581196581196581196581196581
```

This indicates a slow increase, but when I tried small ranges with larger values , the frequency seemed to still increase (above $0.8$). Any ideas ?

Comment: We also found that there were infinitely many non-images of the Carmichael function, right? That is also worth mentioning.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Correct and in fact worth mentioning.

Comment: Maybe try to prove something like certain multiples of a nontotient are nontotient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $V_{\lambda}(x)=\#\{\lambda(n)\leq x : n\geq 1\}$.

By a result of Florian Luca and Carl Pomerance: [https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/rangeoflambda13.pdf](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/rangeoflambda13.pdf)

The number of images of lambda function has an upper bound of the form
$$
V_{\lambda}(x)\leq \frac x{(\log x)^{\eta+o(1)}}
$$
where $\eta=1-(1+\log\log 2)/\log 2=0.0860713..$

Therefore, almost all of $m\leq x$ is non-image of $\lambda$ function.   Hence, we have by $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor - V_{\lambda}(x)$,
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}x=1. 
$$

Later by Kevin Ford, Florian Luca, and Carl Pomerance, [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/lambda_range.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eford/wwwpapers/lambda_range.pdf) it is known that the earlier exponent in the upper bound was in fact the correct one. That is,
$$
V_{\lambda}(x)= \frac x{(\log x)^{\eta+o(1)}}.
$$